# CSS border-spacing property shorthand

Tags: css, border-spacing

It seems to me like the two item standard for most CSS properties is "top/bottom, left/right". At least, that's the case for everything I know of except border-spacing.

Is the "left/right, top/bottom" shorthand for border-spacing intentional? It gets me every time, and perhaps w3 didn't notice it was inconsistent.

Comment: Did you read the question? The two item short hand for most CSS properties is top and bottom, then left and right. Not so for border spacing.

Comment: Considering the sometimes ridiculous amount of time it usually takes W3C to make decisions, I highly doubt it was an oversight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little different because unlike things such as `border-width` or `margin`, only two values are accepted:

```
border-width: 10px 50px 10px 50px; /* valid */
border-spacing: 10px 50px 10px 50px; /* invalid */
```

You can probably chalk it up to this difference.

Whenever you see this shorthand for other properties that accept (up to) 4 values:

```
border-width: 10px 50px;
```

It just means that the bottom and left values are copied from the other side:

```
border-width: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
/*            top  right btm left    */
```

Or with three values:

```
border-width: 10px 50px 20px;
```

This is equal to:

```
border-width: 10px 50px 20px 50px;
```

Comment: Personally I'd just use padding/margin on the table cells and forget border-spacing altogether....